# How to fix "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when running Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, azure-data-lake

I'm getting an error while running the Azure cmdlet in Powershell. How do I resolve this?

I'm trying to get details of folders and files present in Azure datalake through powershell. I'm able to access the data lake through portal and access all files.

Using Azure cmdlet I've tested the connection using "Test-AzDataLakeStoreAccount -Name  $Server" and it works fine too. However, when I execute the below command, it throws null pointer exception. How to resolve that?

```
**Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem -Account "****.azuredatalakestore.net" -Path "/" **


Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem -Account "entadls8cc9b872.azuredatalakes ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataLakeStore.GetAzureDataLakeStoreChildItem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue in both windows powershell and azure cloud shell. It looks like a bug about the powershell module `Az.DataLakeStore`.

I tried `Get-AzDataLakeStoreChildItem -AccountName "AccountName" -Path "/test/"` which is the same as the sample in the doc, also got the same error. I also tried the `Get-AzDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName "AccountName" -Path "/test/123.txt"` and `Test-AzDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName "AccountName" -Path "/test/123.txt"`, both got an error like below.

[image]

I find a github issue related to this error: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8352. I think the format of the commands I have tried should be correct. The [comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8352#issuecomment-455708232) in this issue said 'To use datalake az module you have to use it in netcore powershell (not windows powershell)', but as I know, the  `Az` module is cross-platform, it is not a reason, according to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview?view=azps-2.0.0#run-or-install). Another [comment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8352#issuecomment-486780024) said the 'we have fixed this issue. Apologize for the inconvenience. It will be released as part of next release.'